# RMDatabaseCache causes exponential memory increase

Tags: ios, maps, offline, mapbox

I am trying my luck using Mapbox to download maps for offline usage. But hard luck. There's an exponential increase in memory usage and the app crashes eventually.

I am doing this.

```
RMMapboxSource *onlineSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:kMapboxMapID];

RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:onlineSource];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.774527, -122.420091);

mapView.zoom = 50;
mapView.maxZoom = 50;
for (id cache in mapView.tileCache.tileCaches)
{
  if ([cache isKindOfClass:[RMDatabaseCache class]])
  {
RMDatabaseCache *dbCache = (RMDatabaseCache *)cache;
NSLog(@"current cache size: %lld", dbCache.fileSize);

if (dbCache.fileSize < 20000)
{
  [mapView.tileCache setBackgroundCacheDelegate:self];
  NSInteger minZoom = tileSource.minZoom;
  NSInteger maxZoom = tileSource.maxZoom; // here I am fetching all but this might be too much
  [mapView.tileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:tileSource     southWest:tileSource.latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox.southWest northEast:tileSource.latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox.northEast minZoom:minZoom maxZoom:maxZoom];
}

break;
}
}
```

But the memory shoots and app crashes. 
Anybody can help me ?? Thanks in advance.